# how can I tell a function type from a container type?

Tags: python, python-typing

I am using the typing library and would like to tell a `typing.List` from a `typing.Callable`. I am not sure why the following doesn't work?

```
>>> t = typing.List
>>> isinstance(t, typing.Callable)
True   # why is this true?
>>> isinstance(t, typing.List)
False  # huh??
```

And yes I understand the difference between `==` and `isinstance`. The reason why I was using `isinstance` is because I'd like to know how I can tell that something is a `Callable` w/o knowing its subscripts. For instance:

```
>>> t = typing.Callable[[int], int]
>>> t == typing.Callable
False
>>> isinstance(t, typing.Callable)
True
```

Comment: Being equal to something isn't the same as being an instance of it. `typing.List` is not a list.

Comment: `typing.List` is not an instance of `typing.List`. Similarly, the human species is a species, not a human.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica then why is the statement `isinstance(t, typing.Callable)` True?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: Because the class of `typing.Callable` implements a `__call__` method for its instances.